# jQuery image scroll view with touch and marker support

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, scrollable, markers

I have a large image which should be viewed at 100% zoom and touch scrollable by the user on a mobile device (a scrollable view of 100% width of the device).
When they find the right position in the large image they should be able to place a marker at that position and than save it (So the X and Y point should be retrievable at submit of the form).

What Library is best to use for this? I've searched the web for hours now and I cannot find a solution to my problem. I did find how to make a touch scrollable image, and how to add a marker to an image but getting those together isn't as easy as I hoped.

Is there any library that can do these tasks both?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar project. I am not sure how well this works with the mobile scrollable stuff you have going on, but the marking math would probably be similar. I did not find a suitable library either and ended up writing my own. I don't have that code, but it is relatively straight forward.

There is not really much magic to it. Basically, you want to find the click coordinates (`event.pageX` and `event.pageY`), adjust for the image's `.offset().left` and `offset().top` values, and then compare them to the image's `height` and `width` to calculate the coordinates as a percentage against the image.

The ratio x/y values become important if you ever want to resize the image and have the marks remain in place. You just want to make sure the image in inside a container with `relative` positioning and you can recalculate explicit x/y values as needed.

Something like:

```
var marks = [];
var $img = $("img");

$img.on("click",function(e){

    marks.push({ 
        x: (e.pageX - $img.offset().left) / $img.width(),
        y: (e.pageY - $img.offset().top) / $img.width(),
        id: marks.length
    });

    drawMarks();  
});

function drawMarks(){

    var mCount = marks.length;

    $(".mark").remove();

    while(mCount--){

        var mark = marks[mCount];

        $("<div class='mark' >")
            .data("id", mark.id)
            .appendTo('.holder')
            .css("top", mark.y * $img.width() + "px")
            .css("left", mark.x * $img.width() + "px");  
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K6jwn/